# Reading CSV file into MySQL with subset of columns

Tags: mysql

Given a table 'products' with the following fields:

```
id
name
cost
user_id
```

I want to dump a CSV file containing 'name' and 'cost', and read it back in.

I'm using `SELECT 'name', 'cost' INTO 'data.csv' FROM products;`

How can I use `LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE products;` to read it back in, since some columns are not defined?

Comment: Along the lines of: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'rows.csv' (name, cost) SET id=NULL, user_id=NULL`. [See also this post.](http://ideacode.com/content/mysql-csv-load-fu)

Comment: @bishop `LOAD DATA INFILE 'rows.csv' (name, cost)` worked perfectly, no need for the set statements.  If you put that as an answer ill give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `id` and `user_id` columns have default values set (or accept `NULL`), the statement is simple:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'rows.csv' (name,cost);
```

If those columns need values set, then you can set them per-row at load time:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'rows.csv' (name,cost) SET id=MD5(name),user_id=NULL;
```

MySQL is quite powerful when it comes to filling in values from a source CSV.  Here's a [blog article](http://ideacode.com/content/mysql-csv-load-fu) that shows many of the features in the context of a real world example.